# How to insert enhanced meta file image into worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I need to insert an enhanced meta file image (.emf) to my worksheet. The image has to scale without losing resolution that's why I'm using emf format.

I've tried inserting the image from a memory stream and reading from a file, but somewhere during the process the emf is converted to jpg and no longer scales as the spreadhseet is viewed/printed in different sizes.

Note, when I use Interop.Excel the image inserts as an emf file and scales appropriately. It's when I use EPPlus that I have the problem. I really want to get away from Interop.Excel thought, that's why I'm using EPPlus.

```
// This works as expected, but I don't want to use the interop lib.
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
myXlWorkBook.ActiveSheet.shapes.AddPicture(emfImageFileName, ....);

// This does not. The picture appears in the worksheet but does not scale.
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Drawing;
ExcelPicture pic = myXlWorkSheet.Drawings.AddPicture("Picture Name", new FileInfo(emfImageFileName)); 

// This doesn't work either.
Image img = Image.FromStream(myEmfImageStream);
ExcelPicture pic = myXlWorkSheet.Drawings.AddPicture("Picture Name", img);
```

My expected result should be an Excel worksheet with my image in it that scales properly when viewed/printed in various sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you give it dimensions otherwise everything will be zero:

```
pic.From.Row = 0;
pic.From.Column = 0;
pic.To.Row = 30;
pic.To.Column = 23;
```

As for storing as a JPG, that sounds very strange, it should not randomly convert.  You can confirm if it is or not by opening the XLSX file in 7-zip or rename to .ZIP and open.  You should see the file stored in the media folder.

Also, watch for spaces in the emf file name as I have seen that trip up EPPlus.

### UPDATE

For anyone who might come across this, it is a bug with Epplus.  I have submitted a PR"

https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/496

Comment: Thank you for your help. I looked at the EPPlus source and it's converting all images to the .NET Image class which does apparently does not support .wmf/.emf formats. I'm not sure if there's anything else I can do with EPPlus. SpreadheetLight inserts the image correctly, so I might be forced to use that library, but it only has one author and hasn't been updated in years. Probably not a good choice for the long term.

Comment: @WilliamDrago Your right.  Something I never noticed: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/Drawing/ExcelPicture.cs#L129  Which does exactly the problem you describe.  I might try to fix it and give them a PR.

Comment: I'd be ever so grateful if this was fixed. Perhaps have a look at the SpreadsheetLight source to see how it avoids the issue.

Comment: @WilliamDrago Well, I submitted a PR, we will see how long it is before they read it and/or accept it:  https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/496  Maybe give it an upvote to get it some more attention...

Comment: I up-voted the PR. Thanks for doing that, Ernie. I don't know how they prioritize the PR's and there are some very old ones hanging around, so I don't have much hope for timely acceptance.

Comment: I've never used git or github (we use Mercurial at work), how do I get a copy of EPPlus with your changes?

Comment: @WilliamDrago  It is completely up to the devs to decided when to review and if to merge the changes.  You can always pull my fork (very similar to how hg workds) and compile the DLLs.  Not ideal since they may never decided to merge it in which case you will never be able to get newer versions.  But I would image they will either accept it or fix it themselves.

Comment: I pulled your fork and it does insert .emf files correctly. Any chance of making it work for memory streams containing emf images? I looked at the code and can't figure out how to do it myself. Thanks.

Comment: @WilliamDrago Humm...not sure.  Does it not work as it is right now?  Thew code takes the file "as is" bit for bit.  So it doesnt even know the difference if the file is vector or raster based (or anything else for that matter).

Comment: It works when inserting from a file. It does not work when I try to insert a MemoryStream that contains an emf image. My images are charts that come to my app as MemoryStreams.

   // This works great!
   ExcelPicture pic = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("PicFromFile", new FileInfo(emfImageFile));

   // This does not work. There's no overload to handle the stream.
   MemoryStream emfMemoryStream = GetEmfChartFromLiveChartGenerator();
   ExcelPicture pic = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("PicFromStream", emfMemoryStream);

Comment: @WilliamDrago  I see, its not a bug, its more of a feature request.  If you want to open a new Issue on their GitHub page with some details someone could see about adding it.  I am happy to take a looks but dont know the code well enough to say of the top of my head I can do it.